# Why react lifecycle work everything multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i have problem in react and long time i can't figure out with this.

I can't understand what happened.

What a scenario: 
My app using React and Redux. I keep all my state in redux.

i set some `dataRefreshed` state to redux state for handling re-rendering page when data updated from api.

i'm using **componentWillReceiveProps** lifecycle method.

in my redux state

```
let initialState = {
   dataRefreshed: false
}
```

when my request starting, in redux

```
case START_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        dataRefreshed: false
      };
case SUCCESS_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        dataRefreshed: true
      };
```

So in my component when i make request and get from api new data:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.Reducer.dataRefreshed) {
      apiCall();
    }
  }
```

so if thinking with logic:

1- when my request start and request getting ok status, my dataRefreshed setting true

2- and here nextProps.dataRefreshed and this.props.dataRefreshed not equal.

Till here everything work well. my Condition working and **apiCall()** runned.

but `apiCall` function runned **10 times**

why my state toggling one time so my state turning one to to true from false. But inside condition my function calling million times.

i can't understand what is the logic here.

I'm seriously think anymore living react because of that

Comment: If you are setting a state in apiCall() then it will be in an infinite loop. because it will 
 call componentWillReceiveProps() and componentWillReceiveProps() will change the props again.

Comment: So what to? Have some method in react where nothing working million times?

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code actually does:

1. set dataRefreshed=true
2. trigger props change
3. call apiCall() (cause dataRefreshed==true)
4. START_REQUEST: setting dataRefreshed=false
5. trigger props change (does nothing cause dataRefreshed==false)
6. apiCall got response from server,
7. SUCCESS_REQUEST: setting dataRefreshed=true
8. goto 2 (infinite loop)

You should introduce some flag like shouldRefresh, which will be set to false once data is fetched and not automatically set back to true unless it is meant to.

Comment: yep i got it now

Comment: but if put shouldRefresh flag eg again will be same not?   SUCCESS_REQUEST > shouldRefresh : true . and componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { if (nextProps.shouldRefresh) apiCall() } than it will turn true and componentwillreceiveprops again will go to infinityloop not?

Comment: Why would you set shouldRefresh to true on successful response? The idea is that you don't set it to true unless you want to perform an api call on purpose

Comment: Because i'm trying to make this. first my request update data from api. second api request which working in componentWillReceiveProps it's getting new data from api. So with someway i need to tell my component if first request successed go make second request and get new data

Comment: Are there 2 different api calls? If so, more clarification is needed, cause it is not clear from the problem description.

Comment: I think logic is same not?  i make some post request if request is success i set state to true. and then make second api request in componentWillReceiveProps. if nextProps.LoadingState and this.props.LoadingState is not equal.. there is not important what to do. if you will console log something it will give you million output anyway

Comment: Well then the answer is the same too: don't trigger apiCall() unless it is needed. I.e. don't trigger it on every props change. Or don't change props once apiCall is finished. Otherwise you end up with infinite loop.

Comment: Yes :) I already tried to make what u say but it's nothing happened. my post (first request) working and if only its success i set my state to true and then trying to make this logic. if only loading state is true than call apiCall but it's not happen. i tried componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) if (nextProps.Reducer.LoadingState) apiCall() but its too not worked

Answer (score 0):

Is not that it is doing it twisted. The problem is componentWillReceiveProps method, that’s why react remove it to avoid this type of things

Comment: so what using in this cases ?

Comment: They all the same at the end, but why don’t you instead of using the one. Take a look at shouldComponentUpdate this method receives the previos props and the previous state. Something like this.  “componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.
Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).”

Comment: so shouldComponentUpdate works well? i didn't figure out how it will be works in my case

Comment: i just tried to do that : shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps.Reducer.dataRefreshed)
    console.log(this.props.Reducer.dataRefreshed)
  } and it makes me this output true false true false true false true false.... and million times :)

Comment: Is not that it works well, the difference is that shouldComponentUpdate is not trigger before the first mount https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html sorry if I’m not been clear, but I’m from the cellphone if you could wait a lil bit until I get to work

Comment: If course it is going to do that look at your prop your validating if it change and false !== true there for enters again, and then true !== false that’s also true instead of making something like that compared to and specific value. If your initial value is false compared like is my prop false yes it is oki then call api, then that method is triggered again and you compared the same is my prop false, no it is not oki, do some else